# Replacing a steel wheel

Tags: honda, wheels

My girlfriend is looking for a replacement steel wheel for a 2012 Honda Fit, as one of hers is currently bent. I think they are 15" rims, but I was hoping to find the best option on where to purchase a replacement steel rim. Some local Firestone shop was about to charge her $180 for a new rim, and to move the tire onto the new rim. It was my impression that, that was ridiculously high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds about right for a new factory steel wheel.  You could also try TireRack.com to see if they have any, or some local junkyards for used.  Odds are you're going to have a hard time though, not a lot of junked Fits laying around to get wheels from.  Or, you can use it as an excuse to upgrade to some nice new wheels.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Slightly off-topic, did you considered repairing it?

Depending on how much deformation you have on the rim, you could restore it in a wheel shop. They could hammer it or use a special equipment for reshaping too. Costs in my area start at about 20% of new rims cost.

Comment: My guess is that, that's too risky, but not a bad idea either. She'd rather just have it taken care of.

Comment: Risky in what way? Shops usually give you guarantee on their work.